# C# project created install package on Win7 64 bit machine will not install on Win XP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp, publishing

I am hoping you could resolve this issue. I have made a small application in C# and I publish it with the prereqs of .Net 4.5 and SQL Server Compact 4.0. One of the users of the app is running under an old core which has win XP on it. It appears that .net4.5 will not install on XP for some reason. So I tried to publish a separate configuration with all the prereqs turned off and that did not install either. I am looking for advice how to configure this installation version so this person can run it. What’s the latest version of .NET that can be installed by an XP user?

Any help you can provide will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use .NET 4.5 in your application? If so, you will need those pre-requisites turned on...if not, why add the pre-requisite??

.NET 3.5 SP1 can be installed on XP (a quick google search would have provided this)

For the not being able to install, as you haven't provided any logs etc then we cannot help you much.

Comment: OK I will upload the logs. Is there a way to check and see if you are using .NET 4.5 components